# how to put margin between p and h1 tag?

Tags: html, css

I have call to action bar, inside it there is a h1 tag for slogan and a p tag with a link for actual call to action. I can not marging them properly h1 tag ride on p tag.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdCPb.jpg)

HTML

```
<div id="call-to-act">
<h1>We are Andia, a super cool design agency.We design beautiful websites, logos and prints. Your project is safe with us.</h1>
<p><a href="#" class="call2act">Contact Us</a></p>

</div> <!-- end of call-to-action -->
```

CSS:

```
div#call-to-act {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width: 80%;
}
div#call-to-act p {
    height: 100%;
}


div#call-to-act a.call2act {
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:44px;
    line-height:44px;
    width:120px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;  
}
```

Comment: Include the CSS too. You are probably using float on the `<h1>`

Comment: I've included right now.

Comment: Just remove the `position: absolute` from the `div#call-to-act a.call2act`. You also don't need the `right` and `top`.

Comment: Do not use `position: absolute` if you are expecting margins to make a difference with the surrounding content.

Comment: I've removed but this time it has lost its position, now it stays under h1 tag outside of its container.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I did not understand what's changed and a last question, in order to stay call to action link in the middle should I use this CSS command? 
div#call-to-act a.call2act {
  bottom: 50%;

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mmpMEa

Comment: sorry I've wrongly explained my question, I meant on right side middle.

Comment: this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/mmpMEa

Comment: Almost it is, thank you.If you'd create an answer I'd accept it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;` to put the button on the right side 50% from the top, then `transform: translateY(-50%)` to move the button up half of it's own width to center it vertically. Then apply `padding-right: 130px` to the parent to make room for the `120px` wide button.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#call-to-act {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 46px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 130px;
}

div#call-to-act p {}

div#call-to-act a.call2act {
  text-indent: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #777777;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  width: 120px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="call-to-act">
  <h1>We are Andia, a super cool design agency.We design beautiful websites, logos and prints. Your project is safe with us.</h1>
  <p><a href="#" class="call2act">Contact Us</a></p>

</div>
<!-- end of call-to-action -->
```